# MySQL database design "user" table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a following table in my database. I got a requirement that my USER can be a company or a private user. They have some different specific fields (e.g. in company: company name, person for contact). I am not sure how to achieve this in my database design. Do i have to create 2 separate tables (as it is suggested by normalization rules)? I would appreciate any suggestion!
My USER table:

```
user_id INT <- PK
first_name VARCHAR(35)
last_name VARCHAR(35)
email VARCHAR(254)
password VARCHAR(45)
birthday DATE
creation_date TIMESTAMP
last_access_date TIMESTAMP
updated_at TIMESTAMP
enabled BOOLEAN
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need 2 different tables! One of the options is to have 3-rd table with "user" data from PC viewpoint - store user_id, display_name (compound person or company name), password, last_access, enabled... 2 columns with ID-s will refer to Persons and Companies tables.

Comment: It's up to you but, if it was me, I would insist that ALL individuals belonged to an 'organization' of some sort - although in some instances that might be a 'pseudo-organization' like 'project x client body'. I hope nobody has a 254 character email address. And plain-text passwords aren't a great idea.

Comment: Probably 3 or more tables to get useful schema - account, company, user. Hard to say without knowing more about the application and what a user account means. As such, this is quite a broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design a inheritance mecanism within your database. One of the methods, and the most clean one, is to design three tables:

- A parent **User** table: This table will contain the common fields between company and private users. For example if both company and private users has login and passwords, you user table design will be as follows

> user(user_id, password...)

with user_id as a primary key (You can chose an other primary key based on your needs)

- A **company_user** Table: This will contain the user fields which are specific to company users (other than logins and passwords). This table will have a reference to the login PK of the parent User table

> ```
> company_user(#user_id, company_address...)
> ```

- A **private_user** table This will contain the user fields which are specific to private users (other than logins and passwords). This table will have a reference to the login PK of the parent User table

> private_user(#user_id, home_address...)